# Expo build apk : ExponentToken not generated

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk, token

I created my first expo app, who can send notification to multiple users. I use the expo-notification package to generate the ExponentToken and handle incoming notification.

Everythings works perfecly when I use the expo go app, but recently I build my app in apk with eas

```
$ eas build -p android --profile genAPK
//the genAPK profile : 
build: { 
    "genAPK":{
         "android": {
               "buildType":"apk"
         }
    }
}
```

I downloaded the builded apk, but when my real app want to generate the ExponentToken it just not works and return me a empty string... (I know it  because my app crash do a alert() if the token is empty)

I don't know if this help, but I dont use the firebase way, I use the expo node sdk and my own database and API to store tokens and send notifications

Is this a common mistake and how can I fix this ?
Or at least can I see the output of my package even if this is a apk ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

My notification is also not working when i upgrade to EAS.
And i found this in Expo discord group:

```
No experienceId or projectId found. If one or the other can't be inferred from the manifest (eg. in bare workflow), you have to pass one in yourself.
at http://192.168.7.186:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:102608:321 in _createSuperInternal
at node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/errors/CodedError.js:10:8 in constructor
at http://192.168.7.186:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:313197:49 in getExpoPushTokenAsync$
```

There is a problem with ExpoPushToken, and you can see the source of this error from here [expo-notifications-repo](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-notifications/src/getExpoPushTokenAsync.ts). The cause of this error in my case is the projectId, because in the expo-notifications-repo they use `expo-constant` package which have change in the latest SDK. So i need to add projectId to my app.json

```
"extra":{
  "eas":{
    "projectId":"(PROJECT_ID-Expo.dev)" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh great ! Where did i find this project ID ?

Comment: open your project in expo.dev, open a build, click the Additional Details, and there will be a project ID

Comment: I put it in my app.json but it doesn't work too... I need to put it in the same level than expo in the json right ?

Comment: it should be, the same level as android, hooks, plugins, etc inside expo in app.json